# How do I print one certain character and the character after a space

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to get through this problem without looking at anyone else's code but i'm finding that extremely difficult. I understand how to iterate over characters and print those characters, I think. But i'm really stuck on how to only print one certain one and how to tell it to print the character after the space. Im guessing its something like, space char + 1?

Here is what I have so far, however its isn't much.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for name
    printf("What is your name? ");
    string s = get_string();
    if (s != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen[s]; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", s[0])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to external sites for your code.  Edit the question and put the code in there.

Comment: What is the "one character" you are looking for....? And provide an example of a string and the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, so your first problem is why not?  You didn't bother to tell us what compiler errors you are seeing when you compiled it, so why should we bother to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix that,

> iterate over characters and print those characters

This should be done like that :

```
    int main(void)
    {
    // prompt user for name
      printf("What is your name? ");
      char s[] = "blablabla";
      if (s != NULL)
       {
         for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
         {
            printf("%c", s[i]);
         }
       }
     }
```

> how to only print one certain one

Like that :

```
printf("%c", d[12]); // This will get the 13 (start at 0) char of d
```

> how to tell it to print the character after the space

You idea is the way to go ! The code below will print the next char when
the actual char is a space :

```
int main(void) {
char str[] = "This is a test";

  for (int forward = 0; forward < strlen(str); forward++) { 
     if (str[forward] == ' ' && str[forward + 1] != '\0')
        printf("%c", str[forward + 1]);
  }
}
```

Will print : `iat`

Use a simple **if** statement to check if the **current char is a space** and **the next one isn't the end of the string** and print the next char is the statement is valid.